# How to setup reverse proxy into docker container with local apache

Tags: docker, apache2

I have a apache 2.4.18 and a local nagios installation running successfully on an Ubuntu 16.04 Server with SSL certificates.
There is also a docker running a GitLab image successfully with SSL.
Now I want to run a OpenProject docker image with SSL and need to setup the apache to a "Reverse Proxy", but have no success with that.

I can access Nagios via https://devel.mydomain.com/nagios and Gitlab with https://devel.mydomain.com:4443/ (configured in docker run).

I start the OpenProject container with:

```
sudo docker run -d \
-p 8808:80 --name openproject \
-e SECRET_KEY_BASE=secret \
-v /var/lib/openproject/pgdata:/var/openproject/pgdata \
-v /var/lib/openproject/static:/var/openproject/assets \
openproject/community:8
```

I can access the http://localhost:8808 via wget and get the index.html of OpenProject.

My apache openproject.conf in /etc/apache/site-available file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName devel.mydomain.com

    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLHonorCipherOrder On
    SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS

    SSLCertificateFile       /path/to/ssl/ssl.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile    /path/to/ssl/ssl.key

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/proxyssl_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/proxyaccess.log combined

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8808
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8808

    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

The config is enabled (a2ensite openproject.conf) and apache restart without error.

But I cannot access OpenProject with https://devel.mydomain.com, I only get the Apache default web page.

I try to use a another port, because a ... is already defined in default-ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:4438>
:
```

But https://devel.mydomain.com:4438 response a connection error. The ufw-firewall is configured for allow access from Anywhere.

What detail I missed? 
Which file I should edit too?
How is the correct syntax for the domain in the browser, when alternative port is used?

Thanks in advance for help.

PS: Any correction in the text is welcome but unhelpful. I do not want to improve my language skills, but solve my problem. If something is not understood, please point it out. Then I try to explain it better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking docs here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html
do you really need to set-up the ProxyPassReverse parameter to access the container?

I run multiple environment with proxies set for docker container but using Nginx in front of that.

Comment: Thank you for answer.

_"To ensure that and Location: headers generated from the backend are modified to point to the reverse proxy, instead of back to itself, the ProxyPassReverse directive is most often required: "_

So I think I should do. Behind that is a OpenProject web application, and I think (or suspect) a rewrite of the address is required for functionalities....

See my answer below, I use Nginx now, as you do.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I setup a small Nginx server as reverse proxy and that works like a charm.

Content of snippets/mydomain.com.conf

```
ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl/ssl.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /path/to/ssl/ssl.key;
```

The sites-available/devel.mydomain.com file:

```
server {
    listen 4438 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:4438 ssl default_server;

    include snippets/mydomain.com.conf;

    server_name devel.mydomain.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8808/;
    }
}
```

,'activated' with

```
ln -s ../sites-available/devel.moderndrive.com .
```

...and removing the 'default' config.

After restart, everything works as expected. Nice.

This is, in my opinion, a workaround and not a solution for given problem.

If someone has a solution for a working apache config, I would be glad to read it.

Thank you.